# How to modify Eta pages to use a layout file in Deno?

Tags: javascript, html, deno

I am given the following task and I tried coding it, however I keep getting the same error when I submit it. Any help will be greatly appreciated !

Here is the task:
The assignment template comes with an application with three pages. The code the app.js and the middlewares folder is intentionally a bit cryptic -- do not focus on these files, and instead focus on the Eta pages.

When you look at the Eta pages index.eta, authors.eta, and books.eta, you notice that the header and footer content is the same in all of those fiels. First, extract common content of the pages to the file layout.eta in the folder layouts (within the folder views) -- consider the menu also as common content. Then, modify index.eta, authors.eta, and books.eta so that they use the layout.

Here are the files:
app.js:

```
import { Application, Router } from "https://deno.land/x/oak@v11.1.0/mod.ts";
import { renderMiddleware } from "./middlewares/renderMiddleware.js";

const app = new Application();
const router = new Router();

app.use(renderMiddleware);

router.get("/", ({ render }) => render("index.eta"));
router.get("/books", ({ render }) => render("books.eta"));
router.get("/authors", ({ render }) => render("authors.eta"));

app.use(router.routes());

if (!Deno.env.get("TEST_ENVIRONMENT")) {
  app.listen({ port: 7777 });
}

export default app;
```

middlewares/renderMiddleware.js:

```
import { configure, renderFile } from "https://deno.land/x/eta@v2.0.0/mod.ts";

const renderMiddleware = async (context, next) => {
  configure({
    views: `${Deno.cwd()}/views/`,
  });

  context.render = async (file, data) => {
    context.response.headers.set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8");
    context.response.body = await renderFile(file, data);
  };

  await next();
};

export { renderMiddleware };
```

views/authors.eta:

```
<% layout('./layouts/layout.eta') %>
<h1><a href="/">Books and authors!</a></h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="/books">Check out the books!</a></li>
  <li><a href="/authors">Check out the authors!</a></li>
</ul>
<h2>Authors</h2>
<ul>
  <li>Mike Hebot</li>
  <li>Kent Chanbot</li>
  <li>Kaquhy K. Platt</li>
</ul>
```

views/books.eta:

```
<% layout('./layouts/layout.eta') %>
<h1><a href="/">Books and authors!</a></h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="/books">Check out the books!</a></li>
  <li><a href="/authors">Check out the authors!</a></li>
</ul>
<h2>Books</h2>
<ul>
  <li>The Secret of the Silent Porter</li>
  <li>Liberation of Nebula</li>
  <li>2246: Retribution</li>
  <li>2132: Outbreak</li>
  <li>The Ruins of Zion</li>
</ul>
```

views/index.eta:

```
<% layout('./layouts/layout.eta') %>
<h1><a href="/">Books and authors!</a></h1>
<ul>
  <li><a href="/books">Check out the books!</a></li>
  <li><a href="/authors">Check out the authors!</a></li>
</ul>
```

views/layouts/layout.eta:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <%~ it.body %>
  </body>
</html>
```

error:

```
error: AssertionError
    throw new AssertionError(msg);
```